# How to customize MUI TextField color React.JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the color of the TextField frame? It always appears as black, therefore it's not useful for dark mode. I want to change the color of the label and the input line.

```
return (
    <div
        align="center"
        id="rl-signup"
        className="background h-screen w-screen grid-flow-row auto-rows-auto"
    >
        <TextField
            className="m-auto mb-4"
            id="signup-email"
            label="Email"
            placeholder="cagatay@relink.com"
            helperText="Your organization is ReLink"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            variant="standard"
            required
        />
    </div>
);
```

What should I add to customize TextField color? I want something like this.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

To customize the color of a TextField in Material-UI when using React.js, you can use the input property to apply inline styles to the input element.

For example:

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <TextField
      inputProps={{
        style: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

This will make the text inside the TextField appear in red.